# Why is the kernel couldn't be connected on IBM Watson studio platform?

Tags: kernel, watson-studio

Why is the kernel couldn't be connected to the IBM Watson studio platform?

Comment: hadder Yasser you need to provide more information like which kind of environment and language are you using in your Notebook, datacenter, error message etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the kernel cannot connect because of issues in the underlying environment. If you've tried to modify the python version, Jupyter version, etc through your conda `yml` file, you could cause issues with the environment.

You can also face issues with the kernel connecting if you kill the kernel based on some computation like you try to invert a very large matrix but you don't have enough memory. In that case, try adding more RAM.